# Create a woven material pattern using python for material behavior analysis

Tags: python

Context : the idea is to apply different loads on a sample/specimen made out of woven materials/fabrics and simulate their behavior computationally.

Execution : There are a number of tasks I am required to do. At this point I am only looking for suggestions since I am a beginner in python(not programming). I want to create a woven pattern used in textile manufacturing (atlas weaving) and this pattern is to be described using lines. Each line is to have material properties based on the material/matrix ratio of the fibres.

Recommendation : What python libraries should I look at to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have a sample Material Properties record?

Comment: I haven't received it yet.